# Can you have a css selector with an array index in the middle

Tags: javascript, dom, css-selectors

Hi am trying to run this but it doesn't work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[2] div ul li a');
```

if I remove the [2] then it does, or if I query it separately and store it in a variable and then query that variable then it works:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('div')[2];
div.querySelectorAll('div ul li a');
```

Is there a way to possibly query it all in one go on the chrome console? I did some research and came across something else called nth child and type but I'm curious if this way can work too.

Comment: Do you mean that `document.querySelectorAll('div[2]');` works for you?

Comment: @Andersson nope but ('div')[2] does I'd like to be able to continue adding the other selectors in the same line if possible

Comment: Try `document.querySelectorAll('div')[2].querySelectorAll('div ul li a')` if this is what you need

Comment: @Andersson: I've reopened the question. You can go ahead and post that as an answer.

Comment: @Andersson Great that works as I wanted! thanks I'll accept it as an answer. Why the downvotes for the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want consequently select nodes one by one in single query, try

```
document.querySelectorAll('div')[2].querySelectorAll('div ul li a')
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there's no such thing as array indexes for CSS selectors.

Like you mentioned, you could use [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) for this purpose.

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(2) div ul li a');
```

In this case, the selector matches all *a* elements in *li* elements in *ul* elements in *div* elements in *div* elements that are the second child of another element.

Please note that you should keep your selectors as short as possible to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks, i knew this was is possible, just wondered if the array index way is or not, doesn't seem like it.

Comment: The second div in the document may not necessarily be the second child of its parent. There can be *multiple* divs that are the second children of their parents across the document.